# SharedPreferences cannot save data

Tags: android, facebook, sharedpreferences

I have an issue when I try to save data in SharedPreferences.
Why can't I save data into SharedPreferences normally? 
I have tried several times, but only SharedPreferences works in the other class.
I also know I can't do [this](http://www.codepuppet.com/2013/03/27/saving-a-list-of-strings-in-android-with-sharedpreferences/).

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
        Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            System.out.println("object :  " + object.toString());

            String id = object.getString("id");
            System.out.println("id" + id);
            String name = object.getString("name");
            System.out.println("name" + name);
            String email = object.getString("email");
            System.out.println("email" + email);
            String gender = object.getString("gender");
            System.out.println("gender" + gender);
            String birthday = object.getString("birthday");
            System.out.println("birthday" + birthday);
            JSONObject json_data = ((JSONObject) object).getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data");
            String fb_picture_url = json_data.getString("url");
            URL FBPictureURL = new URL(fb_picture_url);
            System.out.println("profile picture uri" + fb_picture_url);

            SharedPreferences abc = getSharedPreferences("FBProfile",0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = abc.edit();
            editor.putString(PreferenceSettings.fb_id, id);
            editor.putString(PreferenceSettings.fb_name, name);
            editor.putString(PreferenceSettings.fb_email,  email);
            editor.putString(PreferenceSettings.fb_gender,  gender);
            editor.putString(PreferenceSettings.fb_birthday,  birthday);
            editor.putString(PreferenceSettings.fb_picture_url, fb_picture_url);
            editor.commit();
            System.out.println("name" + PreferenceSettings.fb_id);
            System.out.println("name" + PreferenceSettings.fb_name);
            System.out.println("name" + PreferenceSettings.FacebookState);
```

and here is PreferenceSettings with string format, SharedPreferences have not save.

```
public static String fb_id="",
                    fb_name="",
                    fb_gender="",
                    fb_birthday="",
                    fb_email="",
                    fb_picture_url="";
```

Log after saving is no change..

```
07-31 07:20:56.681    9303-9303/? I/System.out﹕ name My Name
07-31 07:20:56.711    9303-9303/? I/System.out﹕ name
07-31 07:20:56.711    9303-9303/? I/System.out﹕ name
07-31 07:20:56.711    9303-9303/? I/System.out﹕ nameMailauthorizing
```

Comment: Try checking the return value of 'editor.commit()', the return value is a boolean

Comment: I think I have terrible mistake with static String and SharedPreferences tag, and already figure it out, thanks everyone reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in onSuccess method. So you can get user data Because if user is not successfully login than you can not get any ser deta from response.

Try this code for SDK 4. It's work successfully. I just made comments form where you should start your code.

```html
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

List < String > permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email",
 "user_birthday", "public_profile", "AccessToken");
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
new FacebookCallback < LoginResult > () {@Override
 public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

  System.out.println("onSuccess");

  String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken()
   .getToken();
  Log.i("accessToken", accessToken);

  GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
  loginResult.getAccessToken(),
  new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {@Override
   public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,
   GraphResponse response) {
    Log.i("LoginActivity", response.toString());
    try {
     id = object.getString("id");
     try {
      URL profile_pic = new URL(
       "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture?type=large");
      Log.i("profile_pic",
      profile_pic + "");

     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
     name = object.getString("name");
     email = object.getString("email");
     gender = object.getString("gender");
     birthday = object.getString("birthday");

     // your SharedPreferences code starts from here.

     SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("myprf",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
     editor.putBoolean("login", true);
     editor.putString("name", name);
     editor.putString("email", email);
     editor.putString("gender", gender);
     editor.putString("birthday",birthday);
     editor.commit();

     Log.i("name", sharedpreferences.getString("name", ""));
     Log.i("email", sharedpreferences.getString("email", ""));
     Log.i("gender", sharedpreferences.getString("gender", ""));
     Log.i("birthday", sharedpreferences.getString("birthday", ""));

     // your SharedPreferences code ends here.

    } catch (JSONException e) {

     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });
  Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
  parameters.putString("fields",
   "id,name,email,gender, birthday");
  request.setParameters(parameters);
  request.executeAsync();
 }

 @Override
 public void onCancel() {
  System.out.println("onCancel");
 }

 @Override
 public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
  System.out.println("onError");
  Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
 }
});
```

Comment: it work, I will check it out where is diff.
I always use my methods for preference, but not this times. Thanks